# How do you view other page content without, opening a page

Tags: html

How do you show content of another page, without opening the other page. I want to display another sites content, but i don't want to open another window, instead i want that website, to be viewed on my site, without opening the other page. I need the HTML code to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other site allows being iframed, this would be the route:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com/"></iframe>
```

It is within the rights of the targeted site to deny access and block such a request.

Comment: How would i make the iframe bigger in size? I want this frame to be the whole page big

Comment: you can style the iframe just like any other element. `iframe {width:100%;height:100vh;min-height:100%;}`